# How to change div background color on click in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

Below is the mark up

```
<mat-card class="example-card" *ngFor="let filteredScreen of 
        filteredScreens"  let i = index >

      <mat-card-header>
          <div mat-card-avatar class="example-header-image" >
              <img mat-card-image class="list-img" src=" 
                {{filteredScreen?.img}}" >
          </div>
            <mat-card-content class="names" [innerHTML]="filteredScreen.name 
              | highlight: name"  >{{ 
                    filteredScreen?.name }}
           </mat-card-content>
      </mat-card-header>
    </mat-card>
```

How can i change the

```
    <mat-card>
```

background color on mouse click(not mouse hover) to any color,and

```
     <mat-card-content>
```

color to any color permanently in angular. I have done changing the background color on mouse hover but i want it on click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `@HostListener`

I have create a demo on **[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3pxz51?file=src/app/highlight.directive.ts)**

```
@HostListener('click') onMouseClick() {
    this.highlight(this.highlightColor || 'red');   
}

 private highlight(color: string) {
    this.el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = color;   
 }
```

Comment: what about text color i mean (<mat-card-content> ) color

Answer (score 3):

directive is a good solution for this kind of thing and can be configurable like color for example and can be reusable on other component mean outside this component and you don't need to add extra logic inside current component.

```
import { Directive, HostBinding, Input,HostListener} from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeStyle } from "@angular/platform-browser";

@Directive({
  selector: '[clickColor]'
})
export class ClickColorDirective {

  private toggle: boolean = false;
  @Input() color: string = 'red';

  constructor(private doms: DomSanitizer) { }

  @HostBinding('style') get myStyle(): SafeStyle {
    let style : string = this.toggle ? `background: ${this.color}` : '';
    return this.doms.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(style);
  }

  @HostListener('click') onClick() {
    this.toggle = !this.toggle;
  } 

}
```

template

```
<div clickColor>
  Hello World from Angular
</div>

<div clickColor color='blue'>
   Angular  World
</div>

<div clickColor [color]="'#000'">
 Batman !!!
</div>
```

[**stackblitz example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-color-div-onclick)

Answer (score 1):

```
<mat-card [ngClass]="{'background-mad': x}" (click)="x = true">
<mat-card-content [ngClass]="{'color-mad': y}" (click)="y = true">
```

in the ts file

```
public x: boolean = false;
public y: boolean = false;
```

And in the css file add for example:

```
.background-mad {
    background-color: red
}
.color-mad {
    color: green
}
```

**EDIT**
html:

```
<span [style.color]="color" (click)="changeColor()">aaaa</span>
```

ts:

```
private list: any = [
    'red',' green', 'blue'
];
  public color: 'black';
  changeColor() {
    this.color1 = this.list[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.list.length)];
  }
```

Comment: I m using this mat-card to display the json data(names),your code is working but its applying to all json data